# different string variable point same address

Tags: c++, string, stl

When I suffered strange string conversion, I found different string variables point same address.

I made 3 string variable in sample. I think a and b should point same address because b is reference variable of a.

But variable c also point same address as a and b. I don`t understand this...

I would really appreciate, if you give me any advice.

---

**Question:**

1. Why do a, b and c variable point same address?
2. After change "c[2]" value, c changed to point different address. Could you explain?
3. What is difference between two approches?

> c[2] = 'z';
>
> // Variable c changed value, but address is still same.
>
> char *temp = (char*)c.c_str(); temp[2] = 'z';

---

compiler version:
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

compile option:
g++ -o test test.c

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print(std::string var_name, const std::string &s)
{
    const char *ps = s.c_str();
    printf("[%s] value=%s, address=%p\n", var_name.c_str(), s.c_str(), ps);
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ab;cd;ef;gh";
    const std::string &b = a;
    std::string c;
    c = b;

    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    print("c", c);

    c[2] = 'z';
    //char *temp = (char*)c.c_str();
    //temp[2] = 'z';

    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    print("c", c);
#if 0
    std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b=" << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c=" << c << std::endl;

    //c[0] = 'z';

    std::cout << "after change";

    char *temp = (char*)c.c_str();
    temp[2] = '1';

    std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b=" << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c=" << c << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

result:

[a] value=ab;cd;ef;gh, address=0x705028

[b] value=ab;cd;ef;gh, address=0x705028

[c] value=ab;cd;ef;gh, address=0x705028

[a] value=ab;cd;ef;gh, address=0x705028

[b] value=ab;cd;ef;gh, address=0x705028

[c] value=abzcd;ef;gh, address=0x705058

Comment: `b` is a const reference to `a` then `b.c_str()` point to same address of `a.c_str()`. Regarding `c`, compiler is free to implement the internal copy. Some compiler choose to [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) instead of copy on copy assignment/constructor. AFAIK, gcc 5.x and clang don't go with copy-on-write.

Comment: IIRC, this copy-on-write behavior was allowed in C++03 but not in C++11 see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html

Comment: In this line `char *temp = (char*)c.c_str();` you break the code by breaking promises and forcing the compiler to ignore it. In order to change a character, `string` provides an `operator[]`. If you used that, you shouldn't get surprising results.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to learn about *references*. A reference is basically an *alias* of something else. Once you initialize `b` as a reference to `a`, `b` is effectively an alias of `a`, and when you use `b` the compiler (one way or another) translates it to `a`.

As for why the addresses are the same, it might simply be an optimization of the compiler and the standard library. Both `a` and `c` are initialized to the same contents, so why not share the contents? Saves memory. When a string is modified it copies the string to its own memory.

---

As for your usage of `temp`, that's very wrong and leads to *undefined behavior*. From [this `c_str` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

> Writing to the character array accessed through `c_str()` is undefined behavior.

The `c` in `c_str` stands for *Constant* (i.e. read-only). That you need to use a C-style cast is indicative of you doing something that might be dangerous and most often bad.

Comment: And the C++11 had stopped allowing copy-on-write http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a reference to `a`. Hence, `b.c_str()` and `a.c_str()` must return the same pointer value.

`c.c_str()` will return the same value as `a.c_str()` only if both point to the same data for efficiency reasons.

It looks like the g++ implementation of `std::string` uses reference counted data. It would make sense, then, that they copy the data only when it is modified.

From file basic_string.h:

> ```
> *                                        [_Rep]
> *                                        _M_length
> *   [basic_string<char_type>]            _M_capacity
> *   _M_dataplus                          _M_refcount
> *   _M_p ---------------->               unnamed array of char_type
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[As Joachim Pileborg said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783723/785671), you have created `b` as an **alias** or  **automatic reference**.

So, whenever you use `b`, you are also using `a`.

For `b` **no actual memory is created** in the data section in your RAM; instead `b` is an alias of `a`.

When it comes to `c`, you have **created actual memory** and you assigned data in `a` to it:

```
std::string c;
c = b;
```

Hence, `c` will have a different memory address to `a`. `b` has the same address as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

std::strings are refcounted , generally a copy on write happens when ever you modify .thats why c's address changes